# Firebase function does not execute for some paths

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is my `firebase.json` for `hosting` and `functions`:

```
 "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "yarn --cwd \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" lint",
      "yarn --cwd \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "dev",
      "public": "public",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/sitemap_index.xml",
          "function": "serveSitemap",
          "region": "europe-west1"
        },
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "ssr",
          "region": "europe-west1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

My `ssr` function looks roughly like this:

```
const universalApp =
  require(`${process.cwd()}/dist/server/main.js`).app;

const app = universalApp(); // Express

export const ssr = functions.region(FUNCTIONS_REGION).https.onRequest(app);
```

When I start the firebase emulator and visit e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml` in my browser, the functions emulator logs the following:

```
[hosting] Rewriting /sitemap.xml to http://127.0.0.1:5001/intergun-dev/europe-west1/ssr for local Function europe-west1/ssr
i  functions: Beginning execution of "ssr"
i  functions: Finished "ssr" in 17.807421ms
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2022:22:35:05 +0000] "GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 339 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0"
```

And I see my sitemap in the browser.  This seems to be working for all files except 2: `favicon.ico` and `robots.txt`.

If I try to visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico`, the following is logged by the emulator:

```
[hosting] Rewriting /favicon.ico to http://127.0.0.1:5001/intergun-dev/europe-west1/ssr for local Function europe-west1/ssr
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2022:22:38:35 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0"
```

Notice that it is correctly rewriting the request to my `ssr` function, but it never executes it! It just immediately returns a 404. The same happens for my `robots.txt` file.

Why won't Firebase execute my function for these files? And it's not just the emulator not working - I have the same issue with the deployed version.

Answer (score 1):

After a whole day of banging my head against a brick wall, I found this issue on Github which explains the issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3734

Apparently, Google Cloud Functions explicitly prevent `robots.txt` and `favicon.ico` from being served... I don't know whether to laugh or to cry at this point.

Comment: Fetal position.